# getting my 2d sprite flip to work depending on a Transform's location from it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, scale

So, this code just isn't responding for whatever reason. I have an enemy that I'm trying to get to face the player at all times (The enemy swoops over the player's head back and forth periodically). But other than making a flip happen whenever a timer hits 0, which doesn't really work all that well, I can't get the Flip function to work. I know the Flipper function is fine; I already tested it out and everything. I'm just not sure how to tell the enemy that when the player is to the left of it, to turn, and vice versa.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class dragoonDetection : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
public Transform Player;
private bool facingRight = true;

void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void Update()
{
    Flip();
}

    void Flip()
{
    if (Player.transform.localScale.x > 0) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1.69f, 1.54f, 1f);
    }
        if (Player.transform.localScale.x < 0) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1.69f, 1.54f, 1f);
    }
}

void Flipper()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector2 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
}
```

Got any ideas? I'd rather avoid using FindGameObject because it's not actually looking for the player script. It's looking for a child transform with no script attached to the player. And because I have two different player GameObjects that you can switch to anytime in the game, it wouldn't really work for me in that regard.

Comment: this looks like it will Flip() back and forth non-stop since one of the conditions within Flip() will always be true. you will need to obtain your player with *some* method and then compare the birds x position with the players x position and flip depending whether or not its >0 or <0

Comment: k i just changed it to be dependent on two booleans that become true or false on another script. The left is when the dragon flies left. the right is when the dragon flies right. But i'm still looking for the enemy dragon to flip which it's not doing.

Comment: do you want it to always face the player? or just have the dragon face the direction it is flying? Flipper() is also never being called here.

Comment: always face the player. I don't have Flipper being called in Update() because it was being called in the Flip function. I just updated the code with a slightly different method. Same results. But I'm leaving Flipper in there just so others can see it.

Comment: If this is a sprite why are you changing the xscale?  why not use the flip bool on the sprite renderer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to perform a check of some sort against the players position with the bird position if you want it to face the player at all times. A barebones method would just be to compare the x-positions of the two objects and change the scale accordingly.

```
void Update()
{
     transform.localScale = new Vector3(getDir()*1.69f, 1.54f, 1);
}

private int getDir()
{
    if (player.transform.position.x < transform.position.x)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 1;
}
```

You should throw some additional checks in here to keep it from updating the scale every frame when there is no change.

Comment: WOW I've never seen return used that way before. I didn't even know that was a thing. Thank you. That totally works. I've never even seen a function called in Update that way before. Totally showed me how much of a noob I am lol. As for your tip on additional checks, I've no idea how to go about doing that lol